# How to remove unnecessary permissions in ios third party sdk?

Tags: ios, objective-c, permissions

My product import one third-party SDK. When the app starts, it will pop up the permission dialog for request to get user location. like this:

[image]

This permission is very sensitive and not necessary. We want to remove this permission in order to protect user privacy.

The application for this permission is in the third-party SDK code, we can't modify it, it will be triggered when the SDK is initialized. In this case, is there a way to remove this permission?

In Android we can use

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" tools:node="remove"/>
```

To remove the extra permissions in the third-party SDK, does the IOS have similar features?

Thank!

Comment: You can swizzle location services and “do nothing” when it’s requested..

Comment: @Brandon Thanks for the reply, can you tell me more details?

Comment: https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/method-swizzling-in-ios-swift-1f38edaf984f